# iOS can we Give access to limited folders or files from drop box?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

Can anyone knows how to give the access to limited folder or files from dropbox. So that i can access only those file or folder from application. I have folder on dropbox root which contains list of songs , I want to give access to that folder only from my iOS app. How to achieve this? Please suggest any way to do this.

I am using dropbox api for the same. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I guess it would be for your app only, NO? Access won't be outside the app..

Comment: i have integrated dropbox in my app. I can access the  root to dropbox and whichever folder kept in it. I need to provide limited access to "xyz" folder in dropbox . How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The available app permissions are here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions.

Your only option would be to get App folder permissions, which would mean your app would get its own folder (named `Dropbox/Apps/<app name>`), and you would have access to only files in there. Otherwise, you'll need to get permissions to the user's entire Dropbox (either Full Dropbox permissions or File type permissions to access only a certain kind of file).